# Strange layout on horizontal orientation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext, screen-orientation, android-orientation

In my `Activity` I have an `EditText` on the `ActionBar` with `android:imeOptions="actionDone"`.
Under it I have a `Fragment`.
It works great on vertical orientation (great = as expected).

However on horizontal orientation the only thing I can see is a big `EditText` with a big button `Done` and keyboard.
It is not styled, I can't see the `ActionBar` nor my `Fragment`.

Is this the standard behavior in `Android` to show an `EditText` like that?
Can I force `Android` not to do this?

Comment: I think you should add this to your acitivy in the manifest  
`android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is standard. It is called extract mode.

You can disable it using:

```
mEditText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_EXTRACT_UI);
```

or

```
android:imeOptions="actionDone|flagNoExtractUi"
```